# Merge the "playlist" tag and "playlists" tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

On the main site, there are two tag that similar:

- [Playlist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playlist)
- [Playlists](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playlists)

How about merge the `Playlists` tag to the `Playlist` tag?

Comment: Thank you - I'll look into it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for noticing and documenting this.

I have merged **playlists** to [playlist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playlist) and **smart-playlists** to [smart-playlist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-playlist).

The plural forms should now be blocked to all but moderators and perhaps a very high level user.